# Sort one column while keeping the other one fixed (within the other)

Tags: r

With

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:3, each = 3)
        , y = rep(1:3, 3)
        , z = round(rnorm(9), 2))

df
  x y     z
1 1 1  0.55
2 1 2  0.99
3 1 3 -2.32
4 2 1 -0.25
5 2 2  1.20
6 2 3 -0.38
7 3 1  1.07
8 3 2 -0.98
9 3 3 -1.09
```

Is there a way to sort `z` within each `x` so that:

```
df.sort
  x y     z
1 1 3 -2.32
2 1 1  0.55
3 1 2  0.99
4 2 3 -0.38
5 2 1 -0.25
6 2 2  1.20
7 3 3 -1.09
8 3 2 -0.98
9 3 1  1.07
```

Thanks!

Comment: How has z been sorted in your example? Within each x value?

Comment: @mnel-- Sorry I was just too stupid to think about the problem in the other way. Your answer actually threw me the hint to order `df` by two columns `with(df, df[order(x, z), ])` which is as common as any other regular question. Thank you for the answer but I guess I could delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort by z within each value of x ( what your example shows, not really what your question seems to lead towards, you can use plyr and arrange

```
library(plyr)
dfa <- arrange(df, x, z)
```

What you are doing here is ordering first by x, then by z

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new `data.frame` on the fly.

```
data.frame(df$x, df[order(df$z), c("y", "z")])
```